# Pale and Bold diagram of loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

It's not really a problem, a question. When someone put data for training a network, tensorboard outputs two diagrams for the loss function, the one which is pale and the other which is bold. I think the bold one is the true one but what is the one which is pale. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is a smoothed version of your loss function

Comment: Yes, that is, found the answer some minute after posting the question